Let’s Encrypt SSL nginx website is slow on ios version 18.2 (run fast on ios version 16.7.10)
I'm config Let's Encrypt SSL with nginx and website. I tested on windows browser, macOS browser and ios version 16.7.10 browser all are working smooth and good performance, but I tested on iphone and IPad version 18.2 was  very slow websites.
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name web.com www.web.com;
         location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
          fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
          fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
          fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
          fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        }

        location / {
        root /var/www/html/www.web.com/build/web/;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html @app;
        }

        location @app {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
server {
    if ($host = www.web.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = web.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80;

         server_name web.com www.web.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

